# Bookmark to localstorage blogspot / blogger

Tags: javascript, local-storage, blogger, bookmarks

Please help for this bookmark widget for blogger/blogspot.

- Please for make toggle button (svg) or can using awesome font if i click bookmark icon for add to bookmark, icon will change function from add to delete. So deleted bookmark list can using this icon or go to modal bookmark list for delete it.
- And maybe some one can add feature for blogger page infinity scroll on homepage, this bookmark is not working.

1. JavaScript

```html
<script>//<![CDATA[
// source code : https://www.hartomy.com/2020/09/cara-membuat-tombol-bookmark-di-blogger.html
var massgEmpty="Daftar Artikel Favorit Belum Ada",articleLabel="Semua konten",link_articleLabel="https://www.wendycode.com/search";!function($){"use strict";var OptionManager=(objToReturn={},defaultOptions={bookmarkIcon:"bookmarkIcon",bookmarkBadge:"show-bookmark",articleQuantity:"article-quantity",affixBookmarkIcon:!0,showBookmarkModal:!0,clickOnAddToBookmark:function(t){},clickOnbookmarkIcon:function(t,e){}},objToReturn.getOptions=function(t){var e=$.extend({},defaultOptions);return"object"==typeof t&&$.extend(e,t),e},objToReturn),objToReturn,defaultOptions,articleManager=function(){var t={};localStorage.konten=localStorage.konten?localStorage.konten:"";var e=function(t){localStorage.konten=JSON.stringify(t)},a=function(){try{return JSON.parse(localStorage.konten)}catch(t){return[]}},o=function(t,o){var n=function(t){var e=-1,o=a();return $.each(o,function(a,o){o.id!=t||(e=a)}),e}(t);if(n<0)return!1;var r=a();return r[n].quantity=void 0===o?r[n].quantity:o,e(r),!0};return t.getAllkonten=a,t.updatePoduct=o,t.setarticle=function(t,n,r,i,c,l){return void 0===t?(console.error("id required"),!1):void 0===n?(console.error("title required"),!1):void 0===r?(console.error("link required"),!1):void 0===l?(console.error("borkimage required"),!1):(i=void 0===i?"":i,void(o(t)||function(t,o,n,r,i,c){var l=a();l.push({id:t,title:o,link:n,summary:r,quantity:i,borkimage:c}),e(l)}(t,n,r,i,c,l)))},t.cleararticle=function(){e([])},t.removearticle=function(t){var o=a();o=$.grep(o,function(e,a){return e.id!=t}),e(o)},t.getTotalQuantity=function(){var t=0,e=a();return $.each(e,function(e,a){t+=a.quantity}),t},t}(),loadBookmarkEvent=function(t){var e=OptionManager.getOptions(t),a=$("."+e.bookmarkIcon),o=$("."+e.bookmarkBadge),n=e.articleQuantity;o.text(articleManager.getTotalQuantity()),$("#cart-modal").length||$("body").append('<div class="pop-area" id="cart-modal"><div class="pop-html"><div class="head-pop"><a class="close-btn buka-tutup">X</a></div><div class="body-content"><span class="table-responsive" id="cart-table"></span></div></div></div>');var r=function(){var t=$("#cart-table");t.empty();var e=articleManager.getAllkonten();$.each(e,function(){t.append('<table class="table"><tbody><tr title="'+this.summary+'" data-id="'+this.id+'"><td class="item-left img-left"><img width="60px" height="60px" src="'+this.borkimage+'"/></td><td class="item-left"><a href="'+this.link+'">'+this.title+'</a></td><td class="item-left" title="Remove favorit" class="text-center" style="width: 30px;"><a class="btn-remove"><svg class="line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g transform="translate(3.500000, 2.000000)"><path d="M15.3891429,7.55409524 C15.3891429,15.5731429 16.5434286,19.1979048 8.77961905,19.1979048 C1.01485714,19.1979048 2.19295238,15.5731429 2.19295238,7.55409524"></path><line x1="16.8651429" y1="4.47980952" x2="0.714666667" y2="4.47980952"></line><path d="M12.2148571,4.47980952 C12.2148571,4.47980952 12.7434286,0.714095238 8.78914286,0.714095238 C4.83580952,0.714095238 5.36438095,4.47980952 5.36438095,4.47980952"></path></g></svg></a></td></tr></tbody></table>')}),t.append(e.length?"":'<div role="alert" id="cart-empty-message"><div class="text-center"><svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19,2L14,6.5V17.5L19,13V2M6.5,5C4.55,5 2.45,5.4 1,6.5V21.16C1,21.41 1.25,21.66 1.5,21.66C1.6,21.66 1.65,21.59 1.75,21.59C3.1,20.94 5.05,20.5 6.5,20.5C8.45,20.5 10.55,20.9 12,22C13.35,21.15 15.8,20.5 17.5,20.5C19.15,20.5 20.85,20.81 22.25,21.56C22.35,21.61 22.4,21.59 22.5,21.59C22.75,21.59 23,21.34 23,21.09V6.5C22.4,6.05 21.75,5.75 21,5.5V7.5L21,13V19C19.9,18.65 18.7,18.5 17.5,18.5C15.8,18.5 13.35,19.15 12,20V13L12,8.5V6.5C10.55,5.4 8.45,5 6.5,5V5Z" fill="#f89000"/></svg><center>'+massgEmpty+'</center><a class="btn btn-outline-info m-2" href="'+link_articleLabel+'">'+articleLabel+"</a></div></div>")};if(e.affixBookmarkIcon){var i=1*a.offset().top+1*a.css("height").match(/\d+/);$(window).scroll(function(){$(window).scrollTop()>=i?a.addClass("bookmarkIcon-affix"):a.removeClass("bookmarkIcon-affix")})}a.click(function(){e.showBookmarkModal?r():e.clickOnbookmarkIcon(a,articleManager.getAllkonten())}),$(document).on("keypress","."+n,function(t){38!=t.keyCode&&40!=t.keyCode&&t.preventDefault()}),$(document).on({click:function(){var t=$(this).closest("tr"),e=t.data("id");t.hide(500,function(){articleManager.removearticle(e),r(),o.text(articleManager.getTotalQuantity())})}},".btn-remove")};$(document).on({click:function(){return $(".pop-area").toggleClass("open"),!1}},".buka-tutup"),$(function(){var goTohartomyBookmark=function(t){};eval(function(t,e,a,o,n,r){if(n=function(t){return(t<58?"":n(parseInt(t/58)))+((t%=58)>35?String.fromCharCode(t+29):t.toString(36))},!"".replace(/^/,String)){for(;a--;)r[n(a)]=o[a]||n(a);o=[function(t){return r[t]}],n=function(){return"\\w+"},a=1}for(;a--;)o[a]&&(t=t.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+n(a)+"\\b","g"),o[a]));return t}('q h=["\\B\\e\\M","\\g\\r\\k\\E\\i\\v\\l\\l\\w\\m\\n\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f","\\x\\y\\f\\g\\C\\k\\y\\k\\y\\F","\\N\\z\\g\\i\\k\\e\\j\\G\\C\\x\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f\\C\\x\\k\\m","\\H\\z\\A\\r\\k","\\F\\y\\H\\z","\\s\\t\\s","\\s\\t\\O","\\s\\t\\P","\\z\\g\\i\\k\\e\\j\\G\\n\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f","\\s\\t\\Q"];q D=[h[0],h[1],h[2],h[3]];(o(b,c){q d=o(a){R(--a){b[h[5]](b[h[4]]())}};d(++c)}(D,S));q u=o(a,b){a=a-I;q c=D[a];T c};$(u(h[U]))[h[9]]({\'\\x\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f\\J\\p\\e\\m\':u(h[6]),\'\\g\\r\\r\\A\\t\\n\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f\\J\\p\\e\\m\':!I,\'\\p\\B\\A\\p\\f\\w\\m\\v\\l\\l\\K\\e\\n\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f\':o(a){L(a)},\'\\g\\r\\k\\E\\i\\v\\l\\l\\w\\m\\n\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f\':o(a){V[u(h[8])](u(h[7]),a)},\'\\p\\B\\A\\p\\f\\w\\m\\v\\l\\l\\K\\e\\n\\e\\e\\f\\j\\g\\i\\f\':o(a){L(a)}})',0,58,"||||||||||||||x6F|x6B|x61|_0x6a0a|x72|x6D|x74|x64|x6E|x42|function|x63|var|x66|x30|x78|_0x3889|x41|x4F|x62|x75|x68|x69|x6C|x2D|_0x4117|x65|x70|x79|x73|0x0|x49|x54|goTohartomyBookmark|x67|x2E|x33|x32|x31|while|0xd6|return|10|console".split("|"),0,{}))});var MyBookmark=function(t,e){var a=$(t),o=OptionManager.getOptions(e),n=$("."+o.bookmarkBadge);a.click(function(){o.clickOnAddToBookmark(a);var t=a.data("id"),e=a.data("title"),r=a.data("link"),i=a.data("summary"),c=a.data("quantity"),l=a.data("borkimage");articleManager.setarticle(t,e,r,i,c,l),n.text(articleManager.getTotalQuantity())})};$.fn.hartomyBookmark=function(t){return loadBookmarkEvent(t),$.each(this,function(){new MyBookmark(this,t)})}}(jQuery);
//]]></script>
```

2. CSS

```css
/* bookmark */
svg.line{width:22px;height:22px;fill:none!important;stroke:#08102b;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-width:1}
.pop-area::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none}
.pop-area{display:flex!important;width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background:rgb(0 0 0 / 51%);visibility:hidden;opacity:0;transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;z-index:999999;overflow-y:scroll}
.pop-area.open{opacity:1;visibility:visible}
.pop-area .pop-html{background:#fff;padding-bottom:10px;display:block;margin:auto auto;width:calc(100% - 20px);max-width:500px;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;transform:scale(.5);border-radius:7px;box-shadow:0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}
.pop-area.open .pop-html{opacity:1;transform:scale(1);visibility:visible}
.pop-area .head-pop:after{content:"Bookmark";color:#fefefe;font-weight:bold}
.pop-area .head-pop{width:-webkit-fill-available;padding:12px 30px;overflow:hidden;background:#f89000}
.pop-area .close-btn{float:right;cursor:pointer;fill:#7e7e7e;color:#fefefe;font-weight:bold}
.pop-area .body-content{padding:10px}
.pop-area .text-center{display:grid;text-align:center;grid-gap:15px}
.pop-area .text-center svg{margin:0 auto}
.pop-area .btn.btn-outline-info{width:fit-content;margin:0 auto;text-decoration:none}
.pop-area .table:hover{border-color:#f89000}
.pop-area .table{transition:all .3s;width:100%;border:1px solid rgba(155,155,155,0.15);border-radius:7px;margin:5px 0;padding:5px}
.pop-area .table img{border-radius:4px;width:auto}
.pop-area .table a:hover,.drK .pop-area .table a:hover{color:#f89000}
.pop-area .table a{text-decoration:none;color:#08102b}
.pop-area .img-left{width:150px}
.pop-area .item-left{padding-right:10px}
.pop-area .btn-remove{cursor:pointer}
.show-bookmark{font-size:11px;line-height:18px;padding:0 5px;border-radius:10px;background:#e6e6e6;color:var(--bodyC);position:absolute;top:-5px;right:0;z-index:2}
.pop-area .counterStat{color:white;font-size:16px}

/* css darkmode sesuaikan class (.drK) dengan templatemu agar dapat berfungsi */
.drK .pop-area.open .pop-html,.drK .pop-area .body-content,.drK .pop-area .table a{background-color:#1e1e1e;color:#fefefe}
```

3. Icon Add Bookmark

```html
<div class='hartomy-bookmark-btn' data-quantity='1' expr:data-borkimage='resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 400, &quot;16:9&quot;)' expr:data-id='data:post.id' expr:data-link='data:post.url' expr:data-title='data:post.title'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><g transform='translate(4.500000, 2.500000)'><path d='M7.47024319,0 C1.08324319,0 0.00424318741,0.932 0.00424318741,8.429 C0.00424318741,16.822 -0.152756813,19 1.44324319,19 C3.03824319,19 5.64324319,15.316 7.47024319,15.316 C9.29724319,15.316 11.9022432,19 13.4972432,19 C15.0932432,19 14.9362432,16.822 14.9362432,8.429 C14.9362432,0.932 13.8572432,0 7.47024319,0 Z'></path><line transform='translate(-4.500000, -2.500000)' x1='12' x2='12' y1='6' y2='12'></line><line transform='translate(-4.500000, -2.500000)' x1='15' x2='9' y1='9' y2='9'></line></g></svg>
</div>
```

4. Icon Notif bookmark

```html
<div class='buka-tutup'>
<svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><g transform='translate(4.500000, 2.500000)'><path d='M7.47024319,0 C1.08324319,0 0.00424318741,0.932 0.00424318741,8.429 C0.00424318741,16.822 -0.152756813,19 1.44324319,19 C3.03824319,19 5.64324319,15.316 7.47024319,15.316 C9.29724319,15.316 11.9022432,19 13.4972432,19 C15.0932432,19 14.9362432,16.822 14.9362432,8.429 C14.9362432,0.932 13.8572432,0 7.47024319,0 Z'></path></g></svg>
<span class='show-bookmark'></span>
</div>
```

I have read all tutorial here but all article same with above issue.

https://www.wendycode.com/2022/02/widget-bookmark-blogger.html